# C++ Pass a hidden arg to a class constructor?

Tags: c++

I would like to define a class that accept the pointer to it's parent class as an Argument, but would it be possible to somehow pass it without needing to pass it directly such as:

```
class Child
{
public:
   Child(Parent* hiddenArg);
};

class Parent
{
public:
   Child myChild;
};
```

I know this is weird, but I am making my own Signal/Slot implementation and Child would be a signal defined, but I would like to get the parent so I can use it's Event Dispatcher...

Comment: Does `Child` inherit from `Parent`?

Comment: Are you thinking of Java nested classes?  They have implicit access to nesting class.

Comment: Child does not inherit from Parent.

Comment: @JP:  That makes the use of "Parent" and "Child" confusing.  Those terms are, in my experience, used to describe classes in an inheritance hierarchy.  Something like "Container" and "Contained" would describe the problem better and not throw people off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do it automatically, but all you need to do is construct `myChild` in the Parent constructor like this:

```
Parent::Parent()
  : myChild(this)   // passing pointer to parent to child constructor
{
}
```

Note some compilers will emit a warning for that code: it thinks you're using the `this` pointer before the Parent class is fully constructed.  As long as you only *store* the pointer in the Child constructor and don't *use* it, you're OK.  You may legitimately want to disable the warning (try not to disable warnings project-wide though - just around the affected area).

Comment: +1 Note that the child constructor should not use the received pointer for anything other than storing it. Passing a pointer to a non fully constructed element (`Parent` in this case) and storing it is correct, but trying to dereference it is undefined behavior.

Comment: Would myChild need to be a pointer in the parent class such as Child* myChild or this would work without needing to new it

Comment: Did you try it?  It should work with the code you posted, where `myChild` is an ordinary member.

Answer (score 2):

If Child is a private, nested class inside parent then this is possible, but I recommend strongly against it.  If Child is a public class, then there is no way to do this.  How could Child possibly know what object (if any) contains it?

In any case, if the Child class is private to parent, you can derive the parent pointer from the child's this pointer.  Something like the following:

```
class Parent {
public:
     ...

private:
    class Child {
    private:
        Parent * GetParentPointer() {
            return (Parent *)((char *)this - offsetof( Parent, m_child ));
        }
    };

    Child m_child;
 };
```

And just to reiterate: don't do this.  No one will care if you "waste" 4 or 8 bytes on an extra pointer inside child, and the resulting code will be much more maintainable.

Comment: Is this all defined behavior according to the standard?

Comment: Wow. It took me a minute to realize that this actually might work, but it's definitely the WRONG solution. I won't downvote it, but no +1 from me!

Comment: @AshleysBrain, I don't think `offsetof` is part of the standard.

Comment: offsetof is an ANSI C macro.  In any case, I did recommend against using it twice.  But I still think it's pretty cool. ;)

Comment: Upvoting this means securing our jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Use a factory

```
class Parent
{ 
  Parent();

  Child* createChild()
  {
    return new Child(this,...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Requires all `Child` classes are on the heap rather than members though.

Comment: If you are worried about creating things on the heap you should not dabble in C++. This has less caveats and is more readable than some of the other solutions suggested here (including the one that was accepted. I would need a more detailed description of the actual problem to come up with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
class Child
{
public:
   Child(Parent* hiddenArg = NULL);
};
```

Comment: How can you access Parent this way?

Comment: This doesn't automatically pass the pointer to the parent class to its Child member, though.